# What is the best solution to merge multiple Xml

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xquery, linq-to-xml

I have a table with an Xml column in Sql. All Xml files have a same schema and I want to merge some of this Xml together.

For example for X1:

```
 <A>
     <B>
         <C id='101'>
             <D id='102'>abcd</D>
         </C>
         <C id='103'>
             <D id='104'>zxcv</D>
         </C>
     </B>
 </A>
```

and X2:

```
 <A>
     <B>
         <C id='101'>
             <D id='102'>abcd</D>
             <D id='501'>abef</D>
         </C>
         <C id='502'>
             <D id='503'>efgh</D>
         </C>
     </B>
 </A>
```

X1+X2=...

```
 <A>
     <B>
         <C id='101'>
             <D id='102'>abcd</D>
             <D id='501'>abef</D>
         </C>
         <C id='103'>
             <D id='104'>zxcv</D>
         </C>            
         <C id='502'>
             <D id='503'>efgh</D>
         </C>
     </B>
 </A>
```

So which choice is the best and how:

- XQuery in Sql
- C# XDocument and XPath
- ...

Comment: You want the union of elements that join by ID?

Comment: @ARZ, Is it possible situation if `<D id='102'>` in X2 has value `12345`? If yes, how to merge these files?

Comment: @ARZ, Kirill Polishchuk to reiterate the point, If elements with matching `id`s have differing values, what then?

Comment: Is the schema as simple as the XML you have posted? Or do you need some code that can do this generally?

Comment: I say preprocess both xml files first and map text node to path. Then traverse one of the files and see if crt node path exists in the other xml's mapping

Comment: @Jodrell,@Kirill Merge the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is to write a class that merges two `XDocument`s using [the visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), with the distinction that we are always visiting nodes from the first document in parallel with nodes from the second document.

The overall design would be something like:

```
class XmlMerger
{
    public XDocument Merge(XDocument first, XDocument second);

    private XElement MergeElements(XElement first, XElement second);

    private XAttribute MergeAttributes(XAttribute first, XAttribute second);

    private XText MergeTexts(XText first, XText second);
}
```

A specific implementation could look like this:

```
class XmlMerger
{
    public XDocument Merge(XDocument first, XDocument second)
    {
        return new XDocument(MergeElements(first.Root, second.Root));
    }

    private XElement MergeElements(XElement first, XElement second)
    {
        if (first == null)
            return second;

        if (second == null)
            return first;

        if (first.Name != second.Name)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var firstId = (string)first.Attribute("id");
        var secondId = (string)second.Attribute("id");

        // different ids
        if (firstId != secondId)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var result = new XElement(first.Name);

        var attributeNames = first.Attributes()
            .Concat(second.Attributes())
            .Select(a => a.Name)
            .Distinct();

        foreach (var attributeName in attributeNames)
            result.Add(
                MergeAttributes(
                    first.Attribute(attributeName),
                    second.Attribute(attributeName)));

        // text-only elements
        if (first.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Any() ||
            second.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Any())
        {
            var firstText = first.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();
            var secondText = second.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();

            // we're not handling mixed elements
            if (first.Nodes().Any(n => n != firstText) ||
                second.Nodes().Any(n => n != secondText))
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            result.Add(MergeTexts(firstText, secondText));
        }
        else
        {
            var elementNames = first.Elements()
                .Concat(second.Elements())
                .Select(e => e.Name)
                .Distinct();

            foreach (var elementName in elementNames)
            {
                var ids = first.Elements(elementName)
                    .Concat(second.Elements(elementName))
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("id"))
                    .Distinct();

                foreach (var id in ids)
                {
                    XElement firstElement = first.Elements(elementName)
                        .SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == id);
                    XElement secondElement = second.Elements(elementName)
                        .SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == id);

                    result.Add(MergeElements(firstElement, secondElement));
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private XAttribute MergeAttributes(XAttribute first, XAttribute second)
    {
        if (first == null)
            return second;

        if (second == null)
            return first;

        if (first.Name != second.Name)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        if (first.Value == second.Value)
            return new XAttribute(first);

        // can't merge attributes with different values
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private XText MergeTexts(XText first, XText second)
    {
        if (first == null)
            return second;

        if (second == null)
            return first;

        if (first.Value == second.Value)
            return new XText(first);

        // can't merge texts with different values
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

If this code encounters something it can't handle (e.g. nodes with the same id but different text; or comments), it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks, but this approach for only two XDocs and must be extended to merge multiple XDocs.

Comment: If you can merge 2 then you can merge them all

Comment: @ARZ, Jodrell is right. Just merge file A and B together, then merge the result with file C, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in XQuery. It is much less code. The example below is done with pure XQuery 1.0. It would be even much easier with XQuery 3.0 (because it supports group by) or with XQuery Scripting.

```
declare variable $sequence := (
   <A> 
       <B> 
           <C id='101'>
               <D id='102'>abcd</D>
           </C>
           <C id='103'>
               <D id='104'>zxcv</D>
           </C>
       </B>
   </A>
  ,
   <A> 
       <B> 
           <C id='101'>
               <D id='102'>abcd</D>
               <D id='501'>abef</D>
           </C>
           <C id='502'>
               <D id='503'>efgh</D>
           </C>
       </B>
   </A>
  );  

declare function local:merge($dsequence) {
  let $dfirst := $dsequence[1]
  let $dextended := <D cid="{$dfirst/../@id}" id="{$dfirst/@id}">{$dfirst/text()}</D>
  return
    if (count($dsequence) eq 1) then
      (: nothing to merge :)
      $dextended 
    else
      (: merging :)
      let $tomerge := local:merge(fn:subsequence($dsequence, 2)) 
      return
        if ($tomerge[@cid eq $dextended/@cid] and $tomerge[@id eq $dextended/id]) then
          $tomerge
        else
          ($tomerge, $dextended)
};

<A><B> {
  let $merged := local:merge($sequence/B/C/D)
  let $ckeys := fn:distinct-values(fn:data($merged/@cid))
  for $ckey in $ckeys
  return
  <C id="{$ckey}"> {
    for $dkey in fn:distinct-values(data($merged[@cid eq $ckey]/@id))
    let $d := ($merged[@cid eq $ckey and @id eq $dkey])[1]
    return <D id="{$d/@id}">{$d/text()}</D>
  }</C>
}
</B></A>
```

Comment: sorry, but how to run it on sql table? ;)

Comment: I am not very familiar with XQuery in an SQL database. How can you access the XML tables from within XQuery? Does it have to be passed from PL/SQL? How does it work?